# Install4J install 3rdparty software depending on the selected language

Tags: install4j

I want to ship a 3rd party software together with my application. I want to include this 3rd party module in the installer. This works, but since i support several languages, i want the Install4 J Wizard to select the file in that language, that was selected. For the default language it works already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the installer variable `${installer:sys.languageId}` in the "Run executable or batch file" action to select a different executable for the 3rd-party installer or to pass it as an argument. If the format is not correct, you add a "Set a variable" action where you transform the language code as appropriate.